# computer science paper: Why t14 and t19 are unreachable and why t19 reachable?

Tags: randomness, software-testing

I am reading the paper[1] at: https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.07147

The paper says in Overview section 3:

> The figure shows a constructed function Bar, which is written in
> Solidity and contained in a smart contract. (The comments should be
> ignored for now.) There are three assertions in this function, on
> lines 14, 19, and 22. A compiler will typically introduce a
> conditional jump for each assertion, where one branch leads to a
> location that fails. Let us assume that we select the failing
> locations (t14, t19 , and t22) of the three assertions as our target
> locations. Note that any target locations could be (automatically)
> selected based on various strategies, e.g., recently modified code
> (for smart contracts under development), assertions (added manually or
> by the compiler for checked errors such as division by zero), etc. Out
> of the above locations, t14 and t19 are unreachable, whereas t22 is
> reachable when input parameter a has value 42.

Somebody please guide me why t14, t19 are unreachable and why t22 is reachable in Figure2 of the paper?

Zulfi.

[1] Valentin W{"u}stholz and M. Christakis, Targeted Greybox Fuzzing with Static Lookahead Analysis,2020 IEEE/ACM 42nd International Conference on Software Engineering (ICSE),2020,789-80.

Comment: What do you think are reachable, and why?

Comment: Thanks. I have provided the link for correct answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskComputerScience/comments/o7fiif/fuzzing_why_t14_and_t19_unreachable_and_t19/). What I understand is that conditions of both the assertions (line#14 and line#19) coincides with the loops.  If the loop does not end we can't access the assertion. But line#22 has no such problem.

Zulfi.